# How to write this case expression with the view pattern syntax?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

After I have read the example of a [RPN calculator](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functionally-solving-problems#reverse-polish-notation-calculator) in "Learn You a Haskell for Great Good!" I wanted to rewrite it myself in a more general way.

In order to easily extend the available functions I put these in separated lists and pattern matched with the `lookup` function using the `ViewPatterns` syntax. To read the input with `read` I wrote this:

```
parse xs x = case readMaybe x of
  Just x  -> Right (x : xs)
  Nothing -> Left "Syntax error
```

but I'd rather avoid a case expression and use again the view pattern like this:

```
parse xs (readMaybe -> Just x ) = Right (x : xs)
parse xs (readMaybe -> Nothing) = Left "Syntax error"
```

However with the latter I'm getting this error:
`No instance for (Read a0) arising from a use of ‘readMaybe’`

I don't understand why. Aren't they equivalent?

The whole code is [here](http://hastebin.com/pabequnaba.hs).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They're not equivalent. The `case` version has one `readMaybe`, the view pattern version has two. For every `readMaybe`, the compiler has to infer which type is the target of the attempt to read. When the code says

```
parse xs x = case readMaybe x of
  Just x  -> Right (x : xs)
  Nothing -> Left "Syntax error
```

the GHC detective notices that in your `Just x` case, `x` ends up consed to `xs`, and so must take whatever type the elements of `xs` have. And that's good work.

But when you write

```
parse xs (readMaybe -> Just x ) = Right (x : xs)
parse xs (readMaybe -> Nothing) = Left "Syntax error"
```

you create two separate find-the-target-type problems, one for each use of `readMaybe`. The first of these is solved in just the same way as in the `case` case, but for the second, read individually,

```
parse xs (readMaybe -> Nothing) = Left "Syntax error"
```

there is just no clue *what* it is that you are failing to read, and no reason to believe it is the same thing as in the line above.

Generally, it is inappropriate to use view patterns unless there is only one outcome of interest. They are the wrong syntax if you want to do an intermediate computation *once*, but analyse the result into more than one case. I am happy to remain on the record that I consider them a misfeature for this reason.

Comment: View patterns are very useful with you have a function with many cases, but the cases are done with functions returning a Maybe, and you never actually pattern match on the intermediate type. Things like `f x | Just y <- g0 x = ...; Just y <- g1 x = ...` versus `f (g0 -> Just y); f (g0 -> Just y)` - the latter is much nicer because it doesn't bind a useless variable (`x` in the first case).

Comment: It's certainly worth supporting pattern matching which makes use of intermediate computations. The trouble is that view patterns give good support only to this Just-or-bust style. We should be able to have more than one bite at the result of an intermediate compuation without having to leave the left-hand side. But I agree that gratuitous extra naming is annoying, so it might be useful to have some more compact notation (when the intermediate computation depends on just one pattern variable and is matched once) and I also want nonlinear patterns instead of an extra name and an equality guard.

Comment: Rnhmjoj: you can still use ViewPatterns, just replace `(readMaybe -> Nothing)` with `_`.

Comment: Certainly, this example can be replaced by a Just-or-bust use of view patterns. It's the general "move case left of =" strategy that's problematic.